# direct global memory access using cuda

Tags: c++, cuda

q1-
lets say i have copy one array onto device through stream1 using cudaMemCpyAsync;
would i be able to access the values of that array in different stream say 2?

```
cudaMemcpyAsync(da,a,10*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,stream[0]);
kernel<<<n,1,0,stream[0]>>>(da);
kernel<<<n,1,0,stream[1]>>>(da){//calculation involving da} ;
```

q2-
would i have to include pointer to global memory array as argument in kernel call? can't i directly access it from the kernel?

```
__global__ void kernel() {out[threadidX.x]=2*input[threadIdx.x];  }
```

instead of

```
__global__ void kernel(float * out,float input){out[threadidX.x]=2*input[threadIdx.x];  }
```

q3-
lets say i have all malloc and memcpy in one function and kernel call in another function and cuda free in another when i call these function they gave invalid argument error?

Comment: For q1, none of your kernel calls are launched into specific streams.  Therefore they will force all previous cuda calls in all streams to complete before they begin.  Therefore yes, as written, those kernels would have access to data placed in `da` by the previous `cudaMemcpy...` operations.  You don't seem to know how to use streams properly.  If your kernel calls were actually issued to another, non-default stream, then there is no guarantee that the data would have been copied into `da` when those kernels begin executing.  regarding q2, `__global__ device ...` is not valid CUDA syntax.

Comment: If you can provide code samples that are consistent with what you are asking about, and are valid CUDA syntax, your questions should be straightforward to answer.  If you cannot, then work on your basic understanding of CUDA syntax before asking questions like these.

Comment: @RobertCrovella so sorry for typos i have corrected....code were means to just show what i am asking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> q1- lets say i have copy one array onto device through stream1 using cudaMemCpyAsync; would i be able to access the values of that array in different stream say 2?

Yes, the array `da` is accessible in both kernels you have shown.  However, an important question is whether or not the previous `cudaMemcpyAsync` operation is complete (or guaranteed to be complete):

```
cudaMemcpyAsync(da,a,10*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,stream[0]);
kernel<<<n,1,0,stream[0]>>>(da);
kernel<<<n,1,0,stream[1]>>>(da){//calculation involving da} ;
```

in the case of the first kernel launch above, the `cudaMemcpyAsync` operation is guaranteed to be complete.  In the case of the second, it is not.  Operations issued to the *same stream* are guaranteed to be serialized, i.e. executed in issue-order.  This guarantees that the `cudaMemcpyAsync` operation will be complete before the kernel launched to the same stream.  CUDA activities issued to *separate streams* may overlap, so there is no guaranteed that the kernel issued to a different stream than the preceding `cudaMemcpyAsync` operation will wait until that operation is complete.

> q2- would i have to include pointer to global memory array as argument in kernel call? can't i directly access it from the kernel?

This appears to be a completely separate question.  *Dynamically allocated* global memory arrays (i.e. those allocated with `cudaMalloc`) will require that you pass a pointer to the allocation to the kernel, if you want to use that data in a kernel.  However a statically allocated array:

```
__device__ int data[SIZE];
```

has *file scope* and you need not (and should not) pass the `data` pointer as a kernel parameter.  That `data` pointer can be used directly in a kernel without explicitly passing it as a kernel parameter.  (Note that you don't use `cudaMemcpy` to populate such an array.)

> q3- lets say i have all malloc and memcpy in one function and kernel call in another function and cuda free in another when i call these function they gave invalid argument error?

I don't think this question can be answered unless you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  SO [expects](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) that you provide an MCVE for "1.Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")"